# Twitter Composer View but no "Compose"/"Submit" button

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, twitterkit

I've been able to get the composer view to appear, but there doesn't seem to be any visible button to submit the tweet. Any ideas on this issue?

```
private func showTwitterShareDialog() {
        let composer = TWTRComposer()
        let url = "somelink"
        composer.setText("Check out \(kShareHashTag), the complete crypto eco system app! \(url)")

        composer.show(from: self.tabBarController!.selectedViewController!) { (result) in
            if (result == .done) {
                print("Successfully composed Tweet")
                self.giveUserReward()
            } else {
                print("Cancelled composing")
            }
        }
    }
```

Using iOS 11, newest TwitterKit from pod (3.1.1)

[image]

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: @GöktuğAral I sort of ditched this option from the app in the meanwhile, so haven't looked to hard into it unfortunately

Comment: change the Navigation bar tint color of the app you should be able to see the buttons